# Write two matrices A and B correctly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I’m currently working on matrices, and this is quite easy for me, however I have hard time to understand how to make these matrices $A$ and $B$ below. *Maybe there is a typo?*

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices with the following entries
$$a_{ij}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
i & \text{for} & i=j-1\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$b_{ij}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{for} & i=j+1\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I shall use these matrices $A$ and $B$ to prove that $[A,B]=I_n-C$ where C is the $(n\times n)$-matrix with entries 0 where the $(n\times n)$’th entry is $n$. I just want to get help to write these matrices $A$ and $B$ and then do the proof by my self.

---

**Edit 1:** My own idea is that my matrices $A$ and $B$ are the following,
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I cannot see how this should give me
$$I_n-C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  0&  0&  \cdots& 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\ 
0 &0  &0  & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0&  0&  \cdots& 0\\ 
0 &0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\ 
0 &0  &0  & 0 &n 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  0&  0&  \cdots& 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\ 
0 &0  &0  & 0 &1-n
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Edit 2:** So thanks to Dietrich Burde I managed to get the answer for $n=2$ since
$$\begin{align*}
[A,B]&=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\text{diag}(1,-1)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=I_2-C.
\end{align*}
$$
But! I cannot get it to work for $n\geqslant 3$.

Edit 3: I corrected my $A$ such that
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots  & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &n-1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and now it works and I can continue with my proof.

Comment: Check the case $n=2$ first. Then $[A,B]=AB-BA={\rm diag}(1,-1)$.

Comment: Yea, I tried now. In the case with $n=2$ I get the same result as you, but what if we use $n=3$? I end $AB-BA=\text{diag}(1,0,-1)$ but this is not equal to $I_3-C=\text{diag}(1,1,-2)$.

Comment: @TheCalcLover1231 From what you have written, it looks like you wrote out the matrix $A$ incorrectly. We should have
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \ddots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & n-1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It looks like the representation matrices of degree $n$ for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. You have to change $B$ accordingly.

Comment: By using the comment from Ben Grossmann I actually ended up with something that works very well. Here I used my $B$ and edited $A$. 

I do not have Lie algebra yet.

Comment: If your $B$ also says $i$ there, these **are** the representation matrices (which I somehow suspect). If not, please ignore my answer.

Comment: Actually it is not $i$ but 1 in my matrix $B$. My first though was that this was a typo, but it is not a typo as I can see from now. I would like to say thanks to everyone who helped to clarify this problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. The use of the Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$ indicates a bit that this is about Lie algebras in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The matrices look (almost) familiar.
Let $V(n)$ denote the $n$-dimensional standard irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$-module. Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be a standard basis for
$\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$. The action on $V(n)$ is given by
$$
  \rho(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & n-1 \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0    
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
\rho(e_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
n-1 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
  \rho(e_3)=\begin{pmatrix} n-1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & n-3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & \ddots & 3-n & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1-n    
\end{pmatrix}
$$
These are then your matrices $A,B,[A,B]$, in case there is also an $i$ in the definition of $B$.